# How can I customize BehaviorSpace 's "Measure runs using reporters"?

Tags: netlogo, reporters, behaviorspace

I would like to use the BehaviorSpace's "Measure runs using reporters" to compile the number of turtles dead `number-dead` for each ticks `ticks`, ID information on living turtle `who` for each ticks, and information on the number of counters `count-up` that the living turtle has for each ticks. I am beginner of Netlogo. I do not know how to set it to "Measure runs using reporters". Already, I was referring to "Netlogo's BehaviorSpace Guide" https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/behaviorspace.html , and then `count turtles` are successful. The following is an example of the input screen of "Measure runs using reporters". However this was a syntax error except `count turtles`.

```
count turtles
count number-dead
count count-up
count who
```

[image: pic]

Comment: Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `number-dead` and `count-up` are breeds that you have defined, then those parts are fine. If they are instead global variables that contain the number of something, then you want to `show` them rather than `count` them. However, `who` is an internal variable that belongs to each turtle so that piece of code doesn't make any sense.

What I suggest you do is create a monitor on the interface for each of the variables that you want in your BehaviorSpace output. So create one monitor for `count turtles` and another for `show number-dead` and so on. When all of those are working for a normal run, then you can do a BehaviourSpace run.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried a test using BehaviourSpace, which was the exception of "who" syntax. This was running with the following error occurred: "COUNT expected input to be an agentset but got the number 10 instead. error while observer running COUNT called by procedure __EVALUATORThe" Also I created each monitor for number-dead and count-up. The obtained cvs. screen is as described above and there are "<ArgumentTypeException>". Do you know how can I get the data?

Comment: Thank you for your additional advice. I tested with "show" command, but it did not work well with syntax error. Are there any other suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Please start a new question for the monitor. If you can't get the monitor to work, then it's pointless to try and get BehaviorSpace to work. That new question needs to have a minimum working example so we can actually see what the variables are, how they are created etc.

Comment: I'm sorry for the question again without setting up a new question. I attempted to display who's information on the monitor, but it was an error. Because, as you already pointed it out, "who" is "turtles-only", and it's true. Actually I was able to export the information as csv data completely. Analysis is also possible using the csv. However, the behavior space is more reasonable way rather than the correcting data by csv. I prefer to use the behavior space if it's possible. The remaining problem is to collect "who" information in the Behavior space. Is this impossible with NetLogo?

Comment: You REALLY need to provide us with some code. You are asking us to guess what you are trying to do. For example, are you trying to list all the who numbers of turtles that satisfy some condition, then you want something like `show turtles with [<condition>`. Try something like that as a monitor and see if if shows what you want. I repeat, get a monitor doing it and then simply copy the code into BehaviorSpace.

Comment: Thank you for the advice again. After that, I putted a variable called ID at the global place, and then I wrote this code "set ID who", and it was confirmed the operation on the monitor also. Then I copied the variable called "ID" to BehaviorSpace, it worked without problems!!!